# Precompiling scss files to css

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt application and i'm including my scss file inside my nuxt.config.js so it gets compiled and available in my application.

```
export default {
...
    css: [
    { src: '~assets/sass/app.scss', lang: 'scss' },
  ]
...
}
```

Now i'm trying to implement an admin section, which will use a different layout.

I am using 2 layout files, default.vue and admin.vue. My goal is to use 'assets/sass/app.scss' for the app that exists at this moment and create a 'assets/sass/admin/app.scss' for my admin section.

The problem is that when i include them both in my nuxt.config.js, they will both be processed. Is there a way to compile the scss files while building, and then included the compiled css files in the head section of the vue layout files?

Comment: Why not have the scss within the layout component itself?

Comment: <style lang="scss" scoped>
@import '.relative/path.scss';
</style>

Comment: scoped only appliies the css to the current layout, not to the child pages and components

Comment: Child pages and components should have their own styling

Answer (score 1):

In your main `App.vue` file you can import your scss file in the style tags.

```
<style lang="scss">
@import "path/to/app.scss"
</style>
```

It should compile.

Comment: Siince it is a nuxt app, everything gets compiled on build, so both css fiiles are actve